# How to use existed Form as Tab in Delphi7

Tags: delphi, pascal

My Delphi 7 application contains multiple forms I've already made. I would now like to make each individual form appear in a separate tab on a single container form. Because I'm new to Delphi, I don't know what approach to take, so what method(s) are available in Delphi for me to accomplish this?

Thanks you.

Comment: I don't see a problem to solve...

Comment: user2047836 - there are three good answers below, would you like to mark whichever solution you're using as correct please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Create a page control, `TPageControl`.
2. Add 7 pages.
3. Create your 7 forms.
4. Add each form into its tabsheet.

The final step is as follows:

```
Form1.Parent := TabSheet1;
Form1.Align := alClient;
Form1.BorderStyle := bsNone;
Form1.ParentBackground := True;
```

Since you are doing this for 7 forms and 7 tabsheets, you'll want to do it in an array, and extract the code above into a method.

Comment: Sometimes I had problems with form alignment, so I added also this two lines:  Form1.WindowState := wsMaximized; Form1.Realign;

Comment: Not sure if it was necessary in Delphi 7 or not, but I've noted in some versions of Delphi that I've also had to add `Form1.SetParentComponent(TabSheet1);` in order to get form to display.

Comment: @LaKraven The documentation tells you not to call that function. Why would you call it? Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan all I know is that on some versions of Delphi, I've had to call it to make the objects display on the parent object.

Comment: @LaKraven It's a TComponent method related to streaming.

Comment: Never thought of making a TForm a child of a non-TForm. Technically speaking, can any TWinControl be a parent of a TForm?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, any windowed control can parent a form

Answer (score 7):

An easy way is to use ManualDock:

```
var
 i:Integer;
begin
    // caption of then new tab sheet will be the caption of the form

    Form2.ManualDock(Pagecontrol1);
    Form2.Show;

    // or as loop
    for I := 0 to 5 do
        begin
          With TForm2.Create(self) do
            begin

                ManualDock(Pagecontrol1);
                Show;
            end;
        end;
     Pagecontrol1.ActivePageIndex := 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of Forms, make them individual Frames, then use the `TFrame` component in individual tabs on a `TPageControl` object to produce the tab layout you desire. This is a code-free solution.

Comment: That works very well until you want to use the forms in standalone mode. But if you never want to do that, then frames are good.

Comment: In that case you can create a simple blank Form, drop a `TFrame` component on it and specify the frame you want.
Of course, this can easily be done at runtime using code too. Frames are a very elegant solution for enabling one distinct layout to be either stand-alone or integrated onto a Form with other objects. I use Frames for compositing on the VCL.

Comment: In my experience that doesn't work so well. But it was ages since I last tried, and I can't remember the problems. So perhaps I'm talking rubbish.

Comment: I've never had any issues using Frames in this way, and I have commercial applications (for many clients) out there spanning the years since the late 90's using them, never once had a complaint of any issues caused by them. Most people have absolutely no idea that I'm using Frames (most of my composite lists simply instanciate a Frame and populate the data for display/actions)